# Static attribute that is True only for a concrete class, and False for its children in Python

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, python-2.x

**The Problem**

Say I have a class `Root` and want to access (e.g. initialise) all its subclasses. But there can be some subclasses that need to be ignored programatically.

**Example**

```
class Root(object):
    pass


class Parent(Root):
    ignore_me = True


class Child(Parent):
    pass


def get_subclasses(klass):
    result = klass.__subclasses__()
    for subclass in result:
        result += get_subclasses(subclass)

    return result


subs = [sub for sub in get_subclasses(Root) if not sub.ignore_me]
```

So what I want here is that `Child` class is included in the `subs` list as opposed to the `Parent` class.

**Trivial Solution**

Of course, I could define the `ignore_me` attribute for each subclass, but the point is that I want to isolate the subclasses from that detail, so that they will not even be aware of it.

**Question**

How can I achieve the goal by just defining the `ignore_me` attribute only in `Parent` class?

Comment: What will you do if you want to make a class that *does* transfer the "ignored" propertyto its subclasses?  That is, what if you want a class `Parent` that wants to specify that not only it but its subclasses should also be ignored by default?

Comment: Hmm..good point :) For full isolation I suspect that it cannot be achieved in any reasonable way. Anyway, suppose the `Parent` classes are much fewer that `Child` classes. Thus, there is no need for propagation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `if sub.__dict__.get('ignore_me', False)` to check if the `ignore_me` property appears directly in the given subclass (not inherited).

However, you will still need to do this differently, because `__subclasses__` only returns the *immediate* subclasses (as [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#class.__subclasses__)).  If you want to recurse through all descendant classes, you'll need to write some code that recursively calls `__subclasses__` on each class in the hierarchy.  Something like this:

```
def getSubs(cls):
    for sub in cls.__subclasses__():
        if not sub.__dict__.get('ignore_me', False):
            yield sub
        for desc in getSubs(sub):
            yield desc
```

Then:

```
>>> list(getSubs(Root))
[<class '__main__.Child'>]
```

Comment: Nice solution, I dove into [Descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html).

Comment: Is it possible to make it "un-hackable"? I mean at least I can manually add the `ignore_me` into the `__dict__` of a `Child` class.

Comment: @n9code: What do you mean "unhackable"?  If you mean can you make it know whether the `ignore_me` was present in the class def or added into its `__dict__` later, then no.  But almost nothing in Python is "unhackable" in that sense.  If someone tries to hack it that way and breaks it, that's their own fault.

Comment: Completely agree with "...almost nothing in Python is unhackable..." What I want is not to protect against the "hacker" but rather the fool.

Comment: I would rather combine your solution with mine, to encapsulate all the implementation details inside the decorator, i.e. the user code will only decorate a class and not care about the insides.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another attempt:

```
class SubclassIgnoreMark(object):
    def __init__(self, cls_name):
        super(SubclassIgnoreMark, self).__init__()
        self._cls_name = cls_name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return owner.__name__ == self._cls_name


def IgnoreSubclass(klass):
    setattr(klass, 'ignore_me', SubclassIgnoreMark(klass.__name__))

    return klass
```

By having these, I can just decorate the `Parent` class with `IgnoreSubclass` decorator...

```
@IgnoreSubclass
class Parent(Root):
    pass

class Child(Parent):
    pass
```

...and then:

```
>>> Parent.ignore_me
True
>>> Child.ignore_me
False
```

Comment: You can just `return owner.__name__ == self._cls_name`

Answer (score 1):

This is actually fairly simple:

```
class Parent(Root):
    @classmethod
    def ignore(cls):
        return cls == Parent

    class Child(Parent):
        pass

>>> Parent().ignore()
True
>>> Child().ignore()
False
```

If you want a class that DO transfer it to subclass, then just replace `return cls == Parent` with `return True`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using virtual subclasses, and override the subclass hook of the virtual subclass.

```
from abc import ABCMeta

class Ignore(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(ignore_cls, cls):
        """only direct, and registered lasses are considered a subclass"""
        return cls in ignore_cls._abc_registry

class Root(object):
        pass

class Parent(Root):
        pass
Ignore.register(Parent) # slightly more elegant in python 3 as register can be used as a decorator

class Child(Parent):
        pass

print(Parent, issubclass(Parent, Ignore))
print(Child, issubclass(Child, Ignore))

def get_subclasses(klass):
    result = klass.__subclasses__()
    for subclass in result:
        result += get_subclasses(subclass)
    return result

result = get_subclasses(Root)
print [cls for cls in result if not issubclass(cls, Ignore)]
```